# Confused twitter after sharing messages on iOS 7

Tags: ios, twitter, ios7

I Integrated twitter with my app for iOS 7, Its working fine first time when sharing on twitter and show me message after sharing "Your Tweet has been sent." which I am showing on `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` case. But what happen when I share same message again on twitter it show me message "The Tweet myappname is a duplicate and cannot be sent." and then it comes to `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` case and show me my message "Your Tweet has been sent." I am not able to get any indication or hint when user sent duplicate message, because at that moment I have to block my own alert. Kindly help me on this that how may I know when user sent duplicate message on twitter. Thanks

**Code:**

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0f)
            {
                SLComposeViewController *twitterController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

```
            // if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
            //{
            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

                [twitterController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                switch(result){
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    default:
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

                    }
                        break;
                    case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    {
                        //                        NSLog(@"Posted....");
                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                            message:@"Your Tweet has been sent."
                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alertView show];


                    }
                        break;
                }};


            [twitterController setInitialText:@"MY App"];
            [twitterController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]];

            [twitterController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
            [self presentViewController:twitterController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

Comment: you cannot send two exact same tweets in short span of time. Its a twitter thing.. not an iOS 7 issue..

Comment: Thanks I understand that, but as developer I have to block my own message on Result Done case when user sent duplicate message in short span of time, Is this possible that twitter give us any hint on duplicate message?

Comment: Then you need to add "NSTimer" in your code if you want to restrict user sending same tweets in short time OR disable 'share' button after successful share is made for a particular time.. But I would still say you don't need to do that because twitter itself is giving you the message "duplicate"..

Comment: Thanks @JohnDoe, I don't want to restrict user to send same or duplicate message I just want to hide my alert which says "Your tweet has been sent." when user sent duplicate message. Possible?

Comment: why don't you add one simple if - condition.. if([message isEqualToString:@"The Tweet myappname is a duplicate and cannot be sent."]){ NSLog(@"Do whatever you want here"); } else { //display alert }

Comment: @JohnDo, Problem is this that I am not getting "message" string in my code, so I am not able to catch the alert message. I am showing my own "SLComposeViewControllerResultDone". Kindly check my update question I attached my code. Kindly look into this and guide me what I have to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: so how do you get this message -> The Tweet myappname is a duplicate and cannot be sent. Why don't you store this message in NSString *message and replace your alertview with UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                            message:message
                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

Comment: @JohnDoe. There is No way for me to get duplicate message, this is coming from Twitter not from my side. This is the reason If I have authority to then I'll deal with this. I have no clue to where this message is coming from.

Comment: Also I have no clue when duplicate message sent.

Comment: @JohnDoe I am not using Webview. I think my problem is bit different as you refer me question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` to assume that the tweet was successful. Also you should leave it to OS to show an alert to the user with appropriate message.

You should not try to dig into the response to get the message. OS will show an appropriate alert in case of error otherwise it will try to play the sound that you configured for successful tweet.